# Print date on weekend only

Tags: java

Dates are input by user, i have a code (as below) to check if the selection range is in Weekends, i would say my code is working, but it is always printing the first chosen date. How do i remove it from the printed list that i have?

```
SimpleDateFormat dfse= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar ce1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar ce2 = Calendar.getInstance();
ce1.setTime(sd);
ce2.setTime(ed);

ArrayList<String> welist = new ArrayList<>();
String dayOfWE = "";
while(!ce1.after(ce2)){
    System.out.println("WE Date: " + dfse.format(ce1.getTime()));
    dayOfWE = "'"+dfse.format(ce1.getTime())+" 00:00:00',";
    welist.add(dayOfWE.substring(0,dayOfWE.length()-1));
    int dayOfWeekE = ce1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dayOfWeekE == Calendar.MONDAY) {
            ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
    } else if (dayOfWeekE == Calendar.TUESDAY) {
            ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 4);
    } else if (dayOfWeekE == Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
            ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
    } else if (dayOfWeekE == Calendar.THURSDAY) {
            ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
    } else if (dayOfWeekE == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
            ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    } else {
            ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    }
    String welistq = welist.toString().replaceAll("(^\\[|\\]$)", "");
    System.out.println(welistq);
```

I have a range chosen (2019-08-16 - 2019-08-20), and it prints

```
WE Date: 2019-08-16
WE Date: 2019-08-17
WE Date: 2019-08-18
WE Date: 2019-08-19
```

17/8/2019 and 18/8/2019 is Saturday and Sunday, it should only print this 2 days, but my code is giving 4 days including 16/8 and 19/8 which is a Friday and Monday.

What do i need to do to make it right?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed the last else if statement and else statement, ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); Shouldn't the else statement points to something else, like  ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 0); maybe?

Comment: @Zubli i tried to add the calendar.date,0 and it went into an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better logic would be to check the day of week for each date after incrementing ce1 by 1 day and adding it to the list if its saturday or sunday

See below

```
package com.so;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class PrintDateOnWeekend {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 2019-08-16 - 2019-08-20

        DateFormat dfse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Calendar ce1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        ce1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);
        ce1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
        ce1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
        System.out.println(dfse.format(ce1.getTime()));

        Calendar ce2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        ce2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
        ce2.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
        ce2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
        System.out.println(dfse.format(ce2.getTime()));

        List<String> welist = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!ce1.after(ce2)) {
            if(ce1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || ce1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                welist.add(dfse.format(ce1.getTime()));
            }
            ce1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        String welistq = welist.toString().replaceAll("(^\\[|\\]$)", "");
        System.out.println(welistq);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, this solve my question!!